# Вывод пользователя не более одного раза

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Пишу скрипт личной почты пользователей.
Хочу вывести на странице новые сообщения пользователя которые он еще не прочитал.
Все это я сделал. Но проблема в следующем: Например, есть пользователь *Максим* и *Вася*.
*Вася* написал пять сообщений **Максиму**. У *Максима* на на страничке вывода новых сообщений выводиться **пять** ссылок на страницу **Васи**.
А нужно вывести всего одну ссылку на страницу **Васи**.
5 ссылок выводиться потому, что *Вася* написал *Максиму* 5 сообщений.
Я хочу сделать чтобы количество ссылок на страницу автора нового сообщения выводило только одну, не зависимо от того сколько он отправил сообщений.
Структура таблицы *mail*: **id** - AUTO_INCREMENT , **id_us** - id того кто отправил сообщение, **id_komu** - id того пользователя которому было отправлено сообщение, **wread** - новое-ли это сообщение(0новое, 1уже прочитано), **date** - дата отправления.
Вот мой код:

```
$MailUS=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `mail` WHERE `id_komu` = '$us[users_id]' AND `wread` = '0' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");
while ($MSGuS = mysql_fetch_array($MailUS))
{
echo "Ссылка на страницу Васи";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо добавить группировку (`group by`) по полю `id_us` (подробнее можно прочитать [здесь](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/18.html)).

И в итоге запрос получится вида:

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE 
id_komu= '$us[users_id]' AND wread= '0' 
GROUP BY id_us
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Тогда все поля, в которых одинаковый `id_us`, будут выведены как одна строка.